# How to use the [(ngModel)] selector property 'path'?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am struggling with this thing that i need to access a nested JSON object array lets say data. I need to access a key which is nested that is below:

> `let data = [{'foo' : {'bar': 'value'}, 'boo' : 'baa'}]`

now we can do data['boo'] to get the string 'baa'. But to get the string 'value' we cant do data['foo.bar']. Now the thing is the value can be 3 level down or 2 level down or directly available. I want a way to access like data['foo.bar'] or data['a.b.c']. this key i am passing from somewhere else. So I believe the **path** **selector** in NgModel is the key to do this. The key i pass is dynamically so if there is a key which is nested I have to write a different function for that which i don't want to.

[image]

Comment: so data here in this is an example, the fact is it can be anything its dynamic meaning it can be possible that the key is 3 level down i.e., {a: {b: {c:  'heyhi' } } } so to fetch heyhi i have to put condition its not certain. if you are getting me

Comment: Why can't you use `[(ngModel)]="data.foo.bar"`?

Comment: that data is my array of object and foo.bar is a string that m passing from somewhere else which can be anything so i have to split it always and also its not static it coulb be just 'boo'  so that data['boo'] or it can be data['foo.bar'] or it can be 3 level down too

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Javascript eval method easily.

Checkout [Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tz4mum)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `split` with reduce?

```
const data = { foo: { bar: 'boo' } };
const key = 'foo.bar';
const boo = key.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], data);
```

You should obviously makes this in a generic function, or perhaps even a `PipeTransform`, where you prevent null pointers